# How to return all results where MySQL record contains substring?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

If, for example, I searched for `#pumpkins` in a text field, all records containing `#pumpkins` should be returned. I'm not sure what MySQL function(s) to use for this. The objective is to replicate the Twitter search functionality, where users can search for any hashtag, and all posts (tweets) containing the hashtag are returned. At first, I thought using the `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions would suffice, but after doing a little more research I'm not so sure.

```
$getHT = "SELECT `post`, `author`, `date`, `id`, `subid`
          FROM `posts` WHERE SUBSTRING(post, LOCATE('$q', post)+7, 
          LOCATE('$q', post) - LOCATE('$q', post) - 7) LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 7";
$seaHT = $con->query($getHT); //Search Hashtags: seaHT
foreach ($seaHT->fetchAll() as $hshtag) { 
    echo '<li><div class="postContent">'. $hshtag['post'] .'</div></li>';
}
```

I tried using preexisting code, but so far to no avail. Would using the `REGEX()` function better suite what I'm trying to accomplish?

UPDATE: Another example:

-User searches for #candy
-Posts column within posts table contains following records

1-"#Candy is sweet"

2-"Pizza is delicious"

3-"Candy is bad for you"

4-"I #love #candy"

-Query returns **only** records 1 and 4.

Using only `LIKE` ('%$q%) currently returns everything, or if I set limits and order the results, it returns the last 7 posts.

```
$query = $_GET['q'];
$q = str_replace('#', '%23', $query);
$getHT = "SELECT `post`, `author`, `date`, `id`, `subid`
FROM `posts` WHERE `post` LIKE '%$query%' AND LENGTH('$q') > 0 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 7";
```

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-select-locate-substring/ It was originally +21, but after it finds a match, its supposed to start the next query from the ending of the previous match. In the link above, 21 was the number of characters of the static match they were searching for. I picked 7 just for testing purposes.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use: WHERE post LIKE '%#pumpkins%'? If you need word-boundaries, you could use REGEXP, e.g. WHERE post REGEXP '#pumpkins[:>:]]'. Both variants won't use an index and queries will become slow, as table size grows.

Comment: I was under the impression that there was something a little more precise. Also, it seems using LIKE by itself doesn't get the correct results either.

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand the problem. Wouldn't it be better, to extract those hashtags/keywords and put them into a new column. On that column create a [Full-Text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for nice performance and more flexible search options.

Comment: Actually, I do already have them extracted and placed into their own table. However, when a user searches for a hashtag, I need to retrieve multiple posts in their entirety containing the hashtag. Not just the hashtag itself.

Comment: Of course, I assume in the hashtag-table you have a column with the [Foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) which is linked to the [Unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) of the main-table (containing the posts), that you can [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) them.

Comment: I do not actually. Currently, the hashtag table has 3 columns (id, hashtag, and times_used). How would you propose I update the hashtag table so that I can join each hashtag to multiple posts? Or is join capable of doing "1 to many" by nature?

Comment: Like @Jonny5 says, i don't see why you can't use LIKE alone! proof http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4deea2/1/0. Are you sure you're not exploding in PHP and comparing an empty string so you're comparing something like '%%' that would be the only reason it's returning everything

Comment: if so try adding AND `LENGTH('$q')>0`

Comment: Hmm, could it be a str_replace() I have in place to change the `#` symbol into `%23`? That just occurred to me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the str_replace, so I tried adding AND `LENGTH('$q') > 0`. Doing so, no results are returned.

Comment: if no results returned you know your $q is an empty string.

Comment: > How ... hashtag to ... posts?

You possibly would need another table that links hashtag-table and post-table, something like tags_to_post. In this new table there could be like 3 columns: id, post_id, tag_id. Depends if the effort and joining,... is worth it. If data size is staying small, I think I'd just put the tags in a column of the main-table and create a fulltext-index on that field, or even do REGEXP/LIKE queries. You said, you get unexpected output. If you want to get exactly, what you search for (even case) try binary collation on the searched columns like utf8_bin or ascii_bin.

Comment: Seems it works fine without the `#` or `%23` in front..

Comment: Happy works for you now :-)